# trying to center a div inside a div that has display table-cell

Tags: html, css

On my site, I have a div set to display: table.  Inside that another div with display: table-row.  Inside that 2 divs set to display: table-cell.  On the first(left) table-cell div, I am trying to center a div.  The only way that div will center is if I stick a div above it with enough content to fill the entire div.

Here is my HTML (with a lot of ugly non-breaking spaces):

```
<section class="main-content">
<div class="row">
<section class="cell leftSide">
<section class="mainWrap">
<div class="clear-fix"></div>
<div class="paddingWrap">
    <div class="widthFiller">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="sitemap">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapTitle()</h1>
        </hgroup>
        @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap()
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    </section>
    </div>
```

And my relevant CSS:

```
.main-content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-content .row {
    display: table-row;
}
.main-content .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
section.mainWrap {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: -34px;
}
.paddingWrap {
    padding: 15px 70px;
}
.mainWrap .sitemap {
    border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: table;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I need that sitemap div to be centered in the mainWrap table cell.  If I remove the "widthFiller" div with all the spaces, the sitemap div goes back to the left side.
And here is my live page that you can view the issue: http://clubschoicefundraising.com/about/site-map

Comment: In order to center something inside a table-cell div, just use text-align: center to the wrapper

Comment: I just went into firebug and applied text-align: center to every div above the sitemap and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to have a display:table-cell you need it inside a table.
so around the div "mainWrap" put another div with the style display:table and width:100%

so:

```
<div class="mainWrapWrapper" style="display:table;width:100%">
 </div class="mainWrap">
  .....
 <div>
</div>
```

currently the issue is that mainWrap will not obey any width css because it is not inside a table div, and when you check it's width it's not 100% so your margin:0px auto on the sitemap will not do anything

Edit: also, you can remove width filler

Comment: I didn't do exactly what you said.  But from your post, I saw that I had a table-cell within a table-cell.  Removed one and voila!  Thanks!